# php5-fpm + nginx + drupal7 : keeps sending me index.php for download

Tags: nginx, php5

Pulling my hairs out here can't figure out why :

My virtual host in /etc/nginx/sites-available/

```
server {
        listen   80 default;

        location /
        {
                root   /var/www;
                index  index.php;                     
        }

        location ~* \.php$
        {
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
```

nginx.conf

```
user www;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;


    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;



    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";


    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

installed packages

- php5-cgi
- php5-fpm
- php5-mysql
- nginx

on fresh clean install ubuntu 11.04.

curl'ing the ip gives me the php file 'not interpreted'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you maximize verbosity of all logs, and paste all log entries associated with your 'non-interpreted' request.

Also, I was setting up a server just yesterday, diff components but same non-interpret result - turned out I just hadn't restarted all appropriate services to pick up the php engine for parsing.

Comment: Right ... i'm really 'dumb' sometimes ... didn't notice the big fat '500' error from PHP. Thanks !

Comment: To elaborate, OP has `default_type application/octet-stream;` So if the backend doesn't provide a mime type such as when errors happen then it will default to application/octet-stream, which is of course a download.